# Vercel Trigger Preview Build only for opened Pull Requests

Tags: bash, vercel

I would like to know if there is a possibility to prevent Vercel preview builds for each commit and rather than make a preview deployment only when any PR is opened and then within each commit.

So the question is, if I can determine in the bash script, that the current branch is already within any opened PR.

Thanks for help